# Ошибка Python IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoap as BS

r = requests.get('https://site.ru/review/new/stopchoice')
html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

for el in html.select('.lent-block'):
    title = el.select('lent-title > a')
    print( title[0].text )
```

> Ошибка Python IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Очевидно, title является пустым списком. Это всё, что здесь можно сказать.

Answer (score 3):

У вас ошибка при парсинге `title`.
Вероятно, вы имели в виду атрибут `.lent-title > a`, а не `lent-title > a`.
Из-за этой ошибки список `title` получается пустым, отсюда и исключение - в пустом списке нет элемента с индексом 0.

Answer (score -1):

Перед получением элемента в массиве по какому-либо индексу, надо бы проверить, что массив имеет соответствующее количество элементов (длину):

```
title = el.select('lent-title > a')
if len(title) > 0:
    print( title[0].text )
```